# Windows 10 - Issues with Airplane Mode + Hibernation Crashes

Tags: networking, windows-10, battery, hibernate, airplane-mode

I have an odd combination of issues with my acer nitro 5 spin 2019 laptop -

I seem to have the airplane mode issue that is frequently identified. When my computer hibernates (when I close the screen), and I turn it back on, I find that it is stuck in airplane mode. When I try to turn it off, the ability to do so is greyed out. I can't even access other menus related to the wifi and network settings when this happens, the only fix that works is restarting the computer. At this point, I'm restarting 1-2 times per day, every time I move somewhere with my laptop. I have updated all drivers and have updated the computer itself to the most recent updates as of 1/20/2020.

The computer also regularly experiences failures when I shut it while it has low battery. I find the battery dies, I get Kernel-Power failure errors, and I have to restart after a blue screen error. No idea why this has happened, updated everything and removed possible malware.

Whats going on? Are these related?

Comment: Are you able to remove Airplane Mode? It has caused me more grief than help and I removed the plan and use Balanced.  Secondly consider turning off Hibernate and use Suspend instead. I do this things, Suspend lasts all day, no crashes, and I turn my laptop off at night and start up the next day

Comment: Thats a good idea - how do I remove it? I've been using balanced, and I guess I was slightly unclear - I meant when my computer sleeps at all this is happening

Comment: Open an admin command prompt.  Type POWERCFG /LIST and note / print the results.  Note the GUID of the Airplane Mode. Then type POWERCFG /DELETE  {GUID of Airplane}  and Enter. List the power plans again and it should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround: make a .reg file to change the state of Airplane Mode. Copy the script below, or go to the key `SystemRadioState` in *Regedit* and export it. Change `00000000` to `00000001` to turn Airplane Mode *on*.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\RadioManagement\SystemRadioState]
@=dword:00000000
```